# How to pass Google Analytics cookies from page contained in iframe, to page on different domain

Tags: iframe, google-analytics, cross-domain, target

Here is my problem: 
We have page contained in iframe (url of iframe page - www.iframepage.com). That page has link UPGRADE on it. When user clicks on that link, he gets directed to billing page, which is located on different domain (www.billingsite.com/cc.html).
That page should be open on top (not in iframe).

If I use _link, GA cookie values will get passed to target page and cross domain tracking will work, BUT target page will open in iframe.

UPGRADE

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiDomainDirectory#_gat.GA_Tracker_._link

I would need a solution that will provide both: target page should open on top (not in iframe) and GA _utm parameters should be passed to target url so cross domain tracking could work.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found solution. Here is code that should be put in body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openWindow(link) {
      _gaq.push(function() {
        var tracker = _gaq._getAsyncTracker();  //add name param if needed
        window.open(tracker._getLinkerUrl(link.href),"_parent");
      });
      return false;
    }
</script>
<a href="www.bilingsite.com/cc.html" onclick="return openWindow(this);" target="_parent">UPGRADE</a></br>
```

Answer (score 0):

The _gaq.push(['_link', url]); function targets the current window with the 'url' you send it. It ignores target. What you need to do is call the Google function but then update the parent location.

Your page within the iFrame should look something link this

`<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>

    <head>



    <script type="text/javascript">

        var _gaq = _gaq || [];

        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxx-xx']);

        _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'example.com']);

        _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);

        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);



        (function() {

            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;

            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';

            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);

        })();

    </script>

    </head>

    <body>



        <a href="/link.html" onclick="your_GA_track_link(this.href);">Link</a>



        <script>

            function your_GA_track_link(url){

                _gaq.push(['_link', url]);

                self.parent.location.href = url;

                return false;

        }

        </script>



    </body>

</html>`

Comment: Thanks for time and help, I really appreciate it! I have tried to implement your solution but as I am not so familiar with JavaScript it did not work out well. Could you please give me example with using this link: www.bilingsite.com/cc.html

Comment: Note: Target opens as parent, but UTM parameters are not transferred so iframe content is set as referral.